# Is there a rule to determine whether or not 「に」 should be attached after 「まま 」?

Tags: grammar, particle-に, adverbs, adverbial

In the example sentences of my textbook for the grammar 〜まま, it is used either with 「に」 (①) or without 「に」 (②,③):
[image]
In the case of ②, I understand that 「に」 is not necessary as まま is not acting as an adverb. Again, at ① it is used as an adverb so 「に」 is attached to it. What bugs me is the example sentence ③. I do not understand why 「まま」 is not attached「に 」even though it is modifying the verb:

> 靴【くつ】を脱【ぬ】がないでそのままお入【はい】りください。

Initially, I thought it might be one of those cases where a particle is ommitted in some instances and both possibilites (namely attaching 「に」or ommitting 「に」) are equally acceptable.

However, I encountered the same sentence later on as part of an exercise where I am asked to pick one option from either:
[image]
so obviously, the only possible option is not to attach「に」to 「まま」just like in the initial example sentence ③.

Why? What am I missing here?

Your help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks to user3856370 for pointing out [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/68980/is-there-a-rule-to-determine-whether-or-not-%e3%81%ab-should-be-attached-after-%e3%81%be%e3%81%be#comment116409_68980) that the「に」in ① comes from the grammar pattern noun+になる (and similarly, noun+にする), where 「まま」 is the noun.The example sentence ① is one of such cases.

> その書類【しょるい】は後【あと】で読【よ】みたいからしまわないで、その**ままに**しておいてください。

Comment: It certainly isn't the whole story, but the まま**に** you are seeing in your book is simply because に is part of the usual nounになる grammar.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. Worth mentioning この/その/あのまま**に**する as well, for which I'm not sure if ままに is either a set expression as whole, it is まま being adverbialised, or it is the typical nounにする grammar pattern.

Comment: にする can also be a set pattern independent of まま. Maybe you should include some of those examples too. Like I said, it isn't the full story. I am aware of some cases where the に does seem to modify まま independently of the rest of the grammar, but I don't feel sufficiently qualified  to talk about them.